# Strange IP address showing up with OS X ssh

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, dtrace

I was futzing around with DTrace on Mac OS X and found the following script that prints out information about connections being established:

> $ cat script.d

```
syscall::connect:entry
{
printf("execname: %s\n", execname);
printf("pid: %d\n", pid);
printf("sockfd: %d\n",arg0);

socks = (struct sockaddr*)copyin(arg1, arg2);

hport = (uint_t)socks->sa_data[0];
lport = (uint_t)socks->sa_data[1];
hport <<= 8; 
port = hport + lport; 
printf("Port number: %d\n", port); printf("IP address: %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
 socks->sa_data[2],
 socks->sa_data[3],
 socks->sa_data[4],
 socks->sa_data[5]);
printf("======\n");
}
```

> I run it in one window:
>   $ sudo dtrace -s ./script.d

Then I ssh to another machine from another window.  I get this output from my dtrace window:

```
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  0  18696                    connect:entry execname: ssh
pid: 5446
sockfd: 3
Port number: 22
IP address: 192.168.0.207
======

  0  18696                    connect:entry execname: ssh
pid: 5446
sockfd: 5
Port number: 12148
IP address: 109.112.47.108
======

^C
```

The first IP address I can explain (192.168.0.207), that's the machine I'm connecting to.
But what's with the 109.112.47.108 machine?  It doesn't show up in tcpdump nor netstat -an

Is there something with my dtrace code or my understanding of how the connect system call works?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out, it's the dtrace script which I grabbed from a Solarius site, needs to be changed for BSD.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a traceroute to that address and see where it is. If it's only a couple of hops away it's probably a firewall or switch.

Comment: 12+ hops, can't ping it either.  It's weird that it just shows up with ssh - but not safari, not ftp, not curl, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a vodaphone IP address in Italy. Are you connected to an ISP in Europe/Italy? If not, better start worrying.

Comment: Check this out, I did the same thing on a G5 with OSX 10.5.8, got the exact same results as on 10.6.4 on intel OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Port 12148 looks like a virus/Trojan issue - best to clean infected system asap

Answer (score 0):

What does `grep 'sshd.*from' secure.log` say? If someone besides you has logged in via SSH then you have a problem. If they haven't it's likely an [unsuccessful brute force attempt](http://stats.denyhosts.net/stats.html). Are you running DenyHosts or Fail2Ban?

I can't find any documentation on syscall::connect, but it looks like it's printing out both ends of the socket. What happens when you run the script and ssh in from another machine?

Comment: Just a bunch of crap.  Doesn't look like it's been compromised.  I'm running both emerging threats iptables firewall rules and denyhosts on the server.

Comment: Apparently doesn't show incoming connections, just looks like outgoing connections.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, this IP appears to be part of the vodafone.it network.  Observe:

```
> host -a 109.112.47.108
Trying "108.47.112.109.in-addr.arpa"
Host 108.47.112.109.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 116 bytes from 68.94.156.1#53 in 180 ms
> host -a 47.112.109.in-addr.arpa
Trying "47.112.109.in-addr.arpa"
Received 112 bytes from 68.94.156.1#53 in 388 ms
Trying "47.112.109.in-addr.arpa.domain_not_set.invalid"
Host 47.112.109.in-addr.arpa not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 139 bytes from 68.94.156.1#53 in 859 ms
> host -a 112.109.in-addr.arpa
Trying "112.109.in-addr.arpa"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20054
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;112.109.in-addr.arpa.  IN ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
112.109.in-addr.arpa. 28800 IN SOA mivsx030.net.vodafone.it. hostmaster.vodafone.it. 9 10800 3600 2592000 900
112.109.in-addr.arpa. 28800 IN NS mivsx030.net.vodafone.it.
112.109.in-addr.arpa. 28800 IN NS gmigdns006.net.vodafone.it.

Received 148 bytes from 68.94.156.1#53 in 373 ms
```